# Should I make a new question or keep the update?

Tags: support, specific-question

Should I make [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30111921/change-uiviews-position-when-iphone-orientation-changes)'s update 2 a new question, or should I just leave it?

I started off with a question about iPhone orientation. Someone wrote an answer that I should be using auto-layout, I shouldn't do it programamtically. I then had a problem with auto-layout.

My question is, should I ask the problem of auto-layout as a new question, or should I update the existing question?

Comment: It's a new problem about a totally different subject. It should be in a new question.

Comment: What you *should* do is try to provide some of the details in this question itself.  The link is nice, but this as-is is a link-only question basically, and it's not really that helpful or useful.

Comment: @nhgrif Updated the question. Thanks for the constructive criticism. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do **neither**.  Do a bit of research.

It's extraordinarily unfair to anyone who has invested any amount of effort in your current question for you to pull the old "your princess is in another castle" trick on them, so dont' edit your question.

But should you ask a new question?  Not yet.

That question was asked just 3 hours ago (as of the writing of this answer).  Three hours ago, you weren't even aware you should be using auto-layout.  There's **no way** you've put in enough research effort surrounding your problem to be ready to ask another question yet.

Give it some time.  Search around.  There's [tons of questions tagged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/autolayout) [autolayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/autolayout) that already have answers.

Comment: Should I remove update 2?