# How do you post a follow up or add code to your original question?

Tags: support

Most sites allow you to post again or edit your original question. I see neither here , how do I do that?

Comment: You can edit. There is an edit link under the post.

Comment: Do you want to *"post a follow up"* (i.e. your previous question has been answered but now you have a different one) or *"add code to [the] original question"* (i.e. the question hasn't been answered and you want to add more information)?

Comment: see also: [Should I make a new question or keep the update?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/293688/839601)

Comment: "Most sites allow you to post again"  - that would be forums. SO is not a forum.

Answer (score 3):

There is an edit button under your post.  It is gray so it can be missed by people not used to looking for it.  There has been some discussion of making it stand out to newer ussers so they notice it.

[image]

Comment: It should not be used for follow-ups though, only for fixing the question.