# Handling near similar questions with minor requirement changes

Tags: discussion, questions, comments

Over the past few days, I answered a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52257476/object-formatting-map-is-removing-my-first-line), that from my first point of view was a well structured question, nl:

- it had a decent description of what the user wanted to achieve
- it had input data relevant to the question
- it had an attempt at solving the problem

A small time after answering, a very similar question title caught my eye on the new posts overview, so intruiged I went to look at it, and it was indeed a near identical question, only now it had received some extra requirements that the user apparently didn't think about.

Considering the meta questions like [Should I make a new question or edit the current one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/293688/should-i-make-a-new-question-or-keep-the-update) and considering that the user did have a new requirement, I had also answered that question, but after answering had a look at the user profiles and this was the 3th question in sequence that had now new requirements.

The question I have would be how I could handle it, so that other use would be more aware of the context of such questions, and how the current code developed.

My current approach was to add a comment, pointing to the near identical question he posed before, and asking him to think on his own, learning from the answers given.

I am however thinking, if I might do him a favor by adding a section to his post, with the following:

> This question is a follow up question from a previously answered question that can be found here.

This would not be to annoy the OP as such, but to point other potential users to the context of how his code came to be. I can see how this might be perceived as unwelcome, but so might the comments be. I do however think that having the previous answers and potential discussions about the answers adds to the context of the question at hand itself.

So, should I:

- Comment such questions with links to the previous questions ;
- Edit the post, to make it clear that it is a follow up question and more context can be found at another place ;
- Ignore all this and move on (which is now my preferred tactic)

Comment: If they're each legitimate questions in their own right and not duplicates of each other, you should probably just move on. Sometimes users abuse this to get others to do their work for them, but there's nothing technically *wrong* with these questions from StackOverflow's viewpoint or anyone who comes across one through a search engine result.

Answer (score -3):

Well, if I am looking for a solution and I find that the question I am looking at is a follow up and I can find more context at another place, I would be very thankful to the guy who edited the post to add it!

Anyhow, when you feel to ignore and move on do it, since most of the times what we feel bleed in what we write. :)

When you say

>
I am however thinking, if I might do him a favor by adding a section to his post

you know more than me that you do a favor to the whole community and not to him. Maybe taking it by this point of view can help in setting yourself in the right mood!

Comment: In this case I don't think linking to previous questions would really help because they are different in their own right based on the requirements. So linking previous posts, even if they are in a series, just adds irrelevant commentary.